# Function as a parameter in Python: How it works?

Tags: python, function, parameters, process

I have two codes as follows. The first one

```
def func_a():
    print('inside func_a')
def func_b(z):
    print('inside func_b')
    return z()
print(func_b(func_a))
```

returns

> inside func_b
> inside func_a
> None

While the second one

```
def func_a():
    print('inside func_a')
def func_b(z):
    print('inside func_b')
    return z
print(func_b(func_a()))
```

returns

> inside func_a
> inside func_b
> None

**Why "inside func_a" is printed before "inside func_b" in the second code**, indicating that the func_a is called prior to func_b?

I check the process [here](https://pythontutor.com/render.html#code=def%20func_a%28%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20print%28%27inside%20func_a%27%29%0Adef%20func_b%28z%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20print%28%27inside%20func_b%27%29%0A%20%20%20%20return%20z%28%29%0Aprint%28func_b%28func_a%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) (for the 1st code) and [here](https://pythontutor.com/render.html#code=def%20func_a%28%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20print%28%27inside%20func_a%27%29%0Adef%20func_b%28z%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20print%28%27inside%20func_b%27%29%0A%20%20%20%20return%20z%0Aprint%28func_b%28func_a%28%29%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=10&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) (for the 2nd code) but don't understand why. Can anyone explain to me? Thank you very much.

Edit: I upload code running results here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OD0ea.png)

Comment: It's not. Your output examples are backwards - `func_a` is called first in the first code example and second in the second code example.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm sorry for the mistakes. I recheck and edit the results and still see the differences. If func_a is called second in the second code, why "inside func_a" is printed first?

Comment: The question is reproducible, so the question should either be reopened or at least be closed for another reason, if applicable. The question was flagged because of a mistake in the code, which was already fixed at the time it got closed (see the comments above).

Comment: Now the answer is just trivial - in the second example, as updated, `func_a` **is** called before `func_b`. Why did you think it _wouldn't_ be? `func_a` is called to resolve the return value that is passed as a parameter to `func_b`, it **must** be called first.

Comment: "Why did you think it wouldn't be [trivial]?" - Because the questioner reiterated, after fixing the issue with the swapped outputs, that this didn't solve his question. The answer may be trivial to us, but it isn't to everybody. For me, this is a valid question to ask, better then a lot of first-time-questions I see around here.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: In the first example you execute `func_a` and passing the return to `func_b`. In the second example you pass the function-object `func_a` to `func_b` where `func_a` is executed after `print('inside func_b')` by the call to z `z()`.

---

To understand this you need to know two things:

1. Functions are first-class objects in python, a function can recieve another function-object as input and/or return a function-object.
2. You call (execute) a function by putting parentheses `()` behind the function-object.

---

So what happens in the first example is:

1. You take the function-object `func_a` and pass it as input to the call of function-object `func_b`. Important: you just pass the function-object without calling it (no parentheses behind `func_a`)
2. You are now inside the `func_b` (because you called it) with z being the function-object `func_a`. Now a few things happen here. In order:

   - `print('inside func_b')` is executed, which results in the first print -> **inside func_b**.
   - The function-object referenced as z (`func_a`) is called, which results in the second print -> **inside func_a**.
   - The return from that last function call, which is `None` as `func_a` doesn't return anything is returned by `func_b`.
3. The `None` that is returned by `func_b` is printed, resulting in the third print -> **None**.

---

The second example works a bit different, all because you call the function-objects at different times:

1. You call the function-object `func_a` (look at the parentheses!). This results in the first print -> **inside func_a**.
2. The call to `func_a` returns `None` which is passed to the call of `func_b`. The following happens:

   - `print('inside func_b')` is executed, which results in the second print -> **inside func_b**.
   - `func_b` directly returns the variable `z` which is `None`.
3. The `None` that is returned by `func_b` is printed, resulting in the third print -> **None**.